# How did these equations go from Step 2 to Step 3?

Tags: statistics, summation

[image]
[image]

Following the example of the 1st equation, why doesn't the 2nd and 3rd equation result in

$$\sum_{all\,x} \,\, \sum_{y:y=x} P(x,y) $$

$$\sum_{all\,x} \,\, \sum_{y:y=z-x} P(x,y) $$
?

Comment: because the results are further simplified. E.g. $\sum_{y:y=x}P(x,y)=P(x,x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. However $$\sum_{y\colon y=z}f(y)=f(z).$$

Comment: How does the simplification remove the summation? Wouldn't it be $$\sum_{y:y=z} f(z) $$ or $$\sum_{all \, z} f(z) $$ ?